# V3: Make two bodies of same collisionType collide with each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am a newbie developer in cocos2d, so please be patient to me. Thanks.

What I am trying to implement is two bodies of the same collision type (They are also not in a custom class, just CCSprite) colliding only with each other and the ground (e.g. debris) and not with anything else. What I don't understand is how to format the ccPhysicsCollisionBegin method. If I format it like this:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair debris:(CCSprite *)debris debris:(CCSprite *)debris2
```

and return YES it will still affect other unwanted bodies, and after a couple of CCLOGs I found out it's never called anyway. So what is the correct way to achieve what I want? Hope what I have requested is possible.

Code used:

```
debris.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:[debris boundingBox] cornerRadius:0];
    debris.name = @"Debris";
    debris.physicsBody.collisionType = @"debris";
    [physicsNode addChild:debris];
```

Comment: Have you set-up the physics bodies correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How can I tell if I did it correctly?

Comment: Show the code you use to set-up the physics bodies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up the `collisionMask`, which defines what the body can collide with.  You should also probably set-up the `collisionCategories` as well:

```
debris.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:[debris boundingBox] cornerRadius:0];
debris.name = @"Debris";
debris.physicsBody.collisionType = @"debris";
debris.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[ @"debris" ];
debris.physicsBody.collisionMask = @[ @"debris" ];
[physicsNode addChild:debris];
```

Comment: Strangely enough, it still keeps colliding with other objects (enemies, projectiles...). Their physics bodies are declared all the same as the above (except different names and collisionTypes, of course). Where could I mess up?

Comment: @TheDood Hmmm, that's unusual and shouldn't be the case.  You are seeing the actual collisions in the game?

Comment: Yes, and for some reason they also don't match the position of the sprites (thanks to the debugDraw I still can see the problem). Only they do this, no any other sprite. Maybe something has to do with me actually allocating this sprite in a for loop?